# Multiple NodeJS apps forward to port 80

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, node.js

I have a server running CentOS. There are a few NodeJS apps running on it.

For example:

- example.com:8000 > My first app
- example.com:8080 > A second app
- example.com:8888 > Another one

The problem I have is that some users have blocked these ports (firewall, etc). I've found some solutions like iptables so you can forward port 80 to 8000. But I have multiple apps so this won't work for me.

Is it possible to forward port 80 with a path after it, something like:

- example.com/firstapp > example.com:8000
- example.com/secondapp > example.com:8080
- example.com/another > example.com:8888

And of course this must work:

- example.com/another/users/123 > example.com:8888/users/123

Comment: It should be done with web-server/reverse-proxy (nginx, apache, varnish, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use NGinx or Apache2 to do it.
I would recommend NGinx with the proxypass,
something like that :

```
location /firstapp {
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```